# content is over lapping the navigation bar

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I'm making the blog site with django I got a problem after adding navigation bar the problem is content of the web site is overlapping the navigation bar when I scroll down the page.
Or if you know how add sticky navigation bar in another better way than this let me know.I used[w3 school web site](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sidebar_responsive.asp)  to add this navigation bar .Anyway here is my code.

```
   {% extends "base.html" %}
      
 {% block content %}
<style>
    
    body {
        font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        background-color: #fdfdfd;
        background-image: url("images/background.png");
    }

    .head_text{
    color: white;
  }
    .card{
    box-shadow: 0 16px 48px #E3E7EB;
}
      #navbar {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
      }

      #navbar a {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 17px;
      }

      #navbar a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        color: black;
      }

      #navbar a.active {
        background-color: #04AA6D;
        color: white;
      }

      .content {
        padding: 16px;
      }

      .sticky {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .sticky + .content {
        padding-top: 60px;
      }
    </style>

    <!-- Nav bar -->
      <div id="navbar">
        <a class="active" href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">News</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Contact</a>
      </div>
      <script>
      window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

      var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
      var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

      function myFunction() {
        if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
          navbar.classList.add("sticky")
        } else {
          navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
        }
      }
      </script>
            <div class="content ">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
      
              <!-- Blog Entries Column -->
              <div class="col-md-8 mt-3 left">
                    {% for post in post_list %}
                <div class="card mb-4" >
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h2 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
                    <p class="card-text text-muted h6">{{ post.author }} | {{ post.created_on}} </p>

                    <p class="card-text">{{post.content|slice:":200" }}</p>
                    <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.slug  %}" class="btn btn-primary">Read More &rarr;</a>
                  </div>           
                </div>

                {% endfor %}
            </div>
                {% block sidebar %}
                {% include 'sidebar.html' %}
                {% endblock sidebar %}
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
{%endblock%}
```

Comment: Look here for sticky: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp

Comment: Can you show a picture?

Comment: Here is google drive link with scrshoot please check the readme.txt file to get the idea https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1aeHeu1izyW0YFCVrNdvfxsSzQLp3HAcD

Comment: I need access. To the file.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1aeHeu1izyW0YFCVrNdvfxsSzQLp3HAcD?usp=sharing done

Comment: Wow That is a problem!

Comment: Update this in your css: `#navbar {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #333;
        z-index: 9999999;
      }`

Comment: If that does not work then add this: `.sticky {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 9999999;
      }`

Comment: Thank you so much Allan finally it work.People who like you make more world beautiful.

Comment: You are very welcome!

Comment: Please mark my answer below as the correct answer, and upvote it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update this in your css:

```
#navbar {
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #333;
   z-index: 9999999;
}
```

If that does not work then add this too:

```
.sticky {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 9999999;
}
Hope it works!
```